# Node app execution on vs code errors out

Tags: node.js

This few lines node app runs into error when I execute directly from ms vs code. However, when I use nodemon it runs without error. node -v and npm -v tells me all is well. nodemon being successful also suggests that all is well. However node app.js from cmd runs into same error. I suspect the Path info but this seem to be correct as well; at least to the best of my knowledge.

See screen capture below.

Folks you help/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]

Comment: possibly a path issue? I'm doubting your app.js is in `C:\Windows`.

Comment: Anthony, you're right, app.js is not in C:\Windows. However, I run node app.js from the directory I have app.js. Any idea on what I should do differently? By the way I moved same app over to another pc and it runs without issues.